# MessageBox launches but does not display

Tags: vb.net, windows

I'm working on a project and I am using a button to show a message box with sample data.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MessageBox.Show("hi")
End Sub
```

Simple enough.
However, when you click the button, I hear the sound that the MessageBox has launched, but the form is never displayed.

I know it has launched because if I try to do anything after clicking the button, I'm locked out.  I have to press enter to acknowledge the MessageBox before I can continue.

This project used to display the MessageBox, but it has stopped.

I've tried several different areas in code, but whenever I show a MessageBox, I get the same results. Any ideas on what I have done?

Comment: Can you see the messagebox on the taskbar? It could just be hidden behind your form.

Comment: Something is putting your messagebox on the back of your main window. You could see it if you press [ALT] + [SPACE] and then move the messagebox window with the arrow keys

Comment: Your code is working for me

Comment: _"Any ideas on what I have done?"_ - I dunno, check source control to see what changed?

Answer (score 0):

never mind, I solved it.

there was a sub that was rendering a picturebox every time the form_paint was called.  It overwrote the messagebox on the screen.